# NGINX - Session management with NGINX as API Gateway

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, session-state

I am new to NGINX and need some clarification. I am deploying NGINX as reverse proxy for my web application which will also work as an API gateway. This API gateway will first send all the HTTP requests to an authentication service (radius based authentication) and then will forward the authenticated requests to the upstream server.
Following are my questions for such a scenario.

1. How does the upstream server knows that the request it received is
   an authenticated request ? Does the authentication service has to
   set some headers in HTTP request after successful authentication ?
   if yes, then which headers ? And the upstream server has to read the same headers to evaluate if the request is authenticated
2. For an authenticated user a typical web server keeps the session
   info with it ? how does the NGINX keeps the session info ? Does
   NGINX keeps the session info for all the clients requesting through
   NGINX reverse proxy ? And is this session info replicated or shared
   with the upstream server as upstream server also needs to keep the
   session info ?
3. When a request is received by NGINX reverse proxy, how does NGINX
   forwards the request to upstream server ? does NGINX keep two
   sessions per request i.e., 1 session from client to NGINX and 2nd
   session from NGINX to upstream server ? OR is it that NGINX doesnt
   keeps any session with it, rather NGINX just forwards/replicates the
   request down to appropriate upstream server.
4. And once authenticated how the authorization (in case of LDAP auth
   groups) details are sent to upstream server ? does upstream server
   have to request these detail to auth server again.

Comment: HTTP is a stateless protocol and it is not the role of the HTTP server to maintain session state. Different frameworks have preferred ways to manage session state, e.g. using cookies.

Comment: so does this mean that every time a request comes NGINX forwards the request to auth module ? what I read was that nginx_htpp_auth_ldap_module authenticates the request and sets the nginxauth cookie in request this way next time when the request ois received by NGINX, it reads the cookie and considers the request as authenticated. https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-plus-authenticate-users/

Comment: Obviously not, it uses a [cookie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie).

Comment: Thanks. What should be done at application level to recognize the authenticated user .

Comment: `Session Persistence` is only for Nginx Plus. I found an open source module https://bitbucket.org/nginx-goodies/nginx-sticky-module-ng/src/master/